# Setting the save file directory and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, directory

I'm new to Python and this in my first script. I'm keen to get it working and hopefully looking for some support to help me break into the language.

My script below saves a url data to csv and the 2 next things i'd like to do is.

1. Specify the folder on the local machine to save to so I don't need the py. file in the same directory. Lets for argument sake say I wan't to save to c:\myfiles and they .py file sits anywhere else on the same machine.
2. I'd like to understand how I can build a variable array in python and loop through my ASXCode variable. To start with let's say I have CSL.ax and BHP.ax as the elements. Ultimately I want to pass this from an external source such as  txt file or SQL table, but for now to help my learning I'm happy with a  static array within this script (baby steps). I assume then I need a For loop or similar to iterate through the elements in my code.

I'm not asking anyone to do it all for me, clues as to the methods/functions and program flow will be great to help me work the solution.

Thanks,

Bassmann

```
import csv
import os
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

ASXCode = 'CSL'
local_filename = "Intra_" + ASXCode + ".csv"
url = ('http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/' + ASXCode +
       '.ax/chartdata;type=quote;range=15d/csv')

temp_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)

with open(temp_filename, 'r', newline='') as inf, \
     open(local_filename, 'w', newline='') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for _ in range(32):   # skip first 32 rows
        next(reader)
    writer.writerows(reader)  # copy the rest

os.remove(temp_filename)  # clean up
print('{} downloaded'.format(local_filename))
```

Comment: Have you tried `local_filename="c:\myfiles\foobar.csv"` to save a file in another folder ? For the second question I don't understant what you cant to acheive. Can you be more precise ?

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks in advance. local_filename = "c:\myFiles\CSL.csv"     work but when I use local_filename = "c:\myFiles\" + ASXCode + ".csv" I get an error EOL while scanning string literal. If I take out the \ at the end of c:\myfiles it runs but saves my file to c:\ and adds myfile to the filename. I must be missing something simple. thanks Bassmann

Comment: For my second part I'd like to have something like this set for the variable ASXCode. e.g. ASXCode = ('CSL, 'BHP'), after that loop the rest of the code for each element in ASXCode. Maybe I'm thinking in terms of other languages, not sure how to approach it right in Python yet.

Comment: Yes. The ` \ ` is an escape caracter (ie. `\"` will put `"` in the string). You should double each ` \ ` (my previous answer was wrong). Try `"c:\\myfiles\\foobar\\" + ASXCode + ".csv"`

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I would have stumbled around for ages trying to figure it out. Saved my a heap of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute the same code for different values of ASXCode, you could do something like that :

```
ASXCodes = ('CSL', 'XXX', 'YYY')
for ASXCode in ASXCodes:
    local_filename = "c:\\myfiles\\foobar\\" + ASXCode + ".csv"
    print("Saving to {}".format(local_filename))
    with open(local_filename, 'w', newline='') as outf:
        ...
print("done")
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, I'd just about got there with the for loop when you're solution popped up. Just 1 more thing on the for loop, this works assuming I want all of my code to loop. But if lets say there a 10 lines of code and I wish to loop the first 5, then run the remaining non looped, is it as simple as placing 'else' after line 5? Have I got this right?

Comment: Python will loop everything that is indented more than the `for`. If you want some code outside the loop, just don't indent it. I have edited my answer.